# Bluebird Promise each in mocha/chai test not working

Tags: sails.js, mocha.js, bluebird, chai

I would like some help to determine why my unit test in a sails.js app is not working as expected.

I am using mocha, chai and bluebird promise library on a sails.js app.

**What I want to achieve:**

- Create a test for TagsService.create(name) method, which accepts a name
  parameter.
- Test that this method will not create a new tag record based on invalid names I pass
- The name parameter is required and should be less than 121 characters long

**What I currently have:**

```js
// Test the 'create' method
describe('Method \'create\' test result: \n', function () {
  
  // Test that name is required and less than 121 chars long
  it('Must receive the name parameter and be less than 121 chars long', function(done) {
  
    // It should not accept any of the following names
    var names = ['',' ','thisstringislongerthanthemaxof121characterslongthisstringislongerthanthemaxof121characterslongthisstringislongerthanthema',[],[{}],[{test: 'test'}],'wrongchars*[]$£%fsf','$%@~}[','£$%jkdfi',' $%"£asdwdFDE','hD8U £$&{DS ds'];
    
    
      sails.bluebird.each(names,function(name){
        TagsService.create(name).then(function(data){
          assert.propertyVal(data,'status','err','An error was NOT returned - even though names provided should be invalid');
        });
      }).then(function(){
        done();
      });
    
  
   });
  
});
```

What happens is it seems to pass, even if I pass in a valid name or return null from the method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, looks like I managed to solve it, after much trial and error.

Turns out I need to catch the done() callback from the Promise after the each method executed. Also needed to return the result of the tests done from the TagsService promise object. (Still not 100% sure this is the correct way to think about it..). Anyway the test seems to function properly now.

Here is my result:

```js
var names = ['',' ','thisstringislongerthanthemaxof121characterslongthisstringislongerthanthemaxof121characterslongthisstringislongerthanthema',[],[{}],[{test: 'test'}],'wrongchars*[]$%fsf','$%@~}[','�$%jkdfi',' $%"�asdwdFDE','hD8U �$&{DS ds'];
   
sails.bluebird.each(names, function(name){
    return TagsService.create(name).then(function(data) {
 assert.property(data, 'status', 'create method did not return a status property');
 assert(data.status === 'err', 'even with an invalid name parameter passed - it did not return an err status, which it must do with an invalid name.');
    });
}).then(function(){
 done();
}).catch(done);
```